# How to edit one item sortable without use tablecontente

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a *sortable* that it was loaded from JSON files.
This is a sortable's jquery http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable

But I want to edit one item. The item before is inserted from the user. Looking the http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable for example I want Item 3. How?

Now I want to edit one item for example Little birds, with **JavaScript** or **jQuery**, with one variable's string. This variable is inserted from a user in a `textarea`.(this i know).

How to edit the item's sortable using the variable???

I receive from a `textarea` the element name that I have to cancel.

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

I know how you analyze the list but edit (change) the name's item's sortable?

**The HTML code of the *sortable*:**

```
<div id="sortparam">

<ul style="" class="ui-sortable" id="sortable">
    <li style="" id="1" class="ui-state-default"> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Singular sensation</li>
    <li style="" id="2" class="ui-state-default"> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Beady little eyes</li>
    <li style="" id="3" class="ui-state-default"> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Little birds </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Please, I don't want `contenteditable`

Comment: where is your `textarea`? post that html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to target text nodes or replace the full html of the element. We have no way to know how you intend to target which sortable gets edited.

Following solution stores the icon html, and updates full html of the element.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/WZeMH/

```
/* no relationship given on how to determine which sortable to edit use second one*/
var whichSortable= 2;

/* define sortable element to edit */
var $sortableEl=$('#'+whichSortable);

/* store icon span html string*/
var iconSpan=$('<div>').append( $sortableEl.find('.ui-icon').clone() ).html();

$('textarea').keyup(function(){
    var val=$(this).val();
     $sortableEl.html( iconSpan + val);    
})
```

Comment: How to save the new text of item's sortable?

Comment: if you mean save to server would have to use ajax

Comment: For the people (use form with medoth GET)

Answer (score 0):

**Just an example:**

Suppose, you've a `textbox` like following:

```
<input type="text" id="your_text">
```

Now you can bind `keyup` event to that `textbox` and using the text update sortable `li`'s content.

```
var li = $('#sortable li#3'),           // reference of li
    originalVal = li.text(),            // keep reference of original 
                                        // text(e.g Little birds)
    iconSpan = li.find('span.ui-icon'); // take the span icon

$('#your_text').keyup(function() {       // bind a keyup event
  var val = $.trim( this.value );        // take new value on each keyup
  if( val ) {                            // if new value entered
    li.html( iconSpan + val );           // set new value to little birds
  } else {                               // if text box is empty
     li.html( iconSpan + originalVal );  // set original value
  }
});
```

But I think you should have equal number of `textbox` to number of `sortable` elements and you may catch the value of `textbox` through other process.

Comment: unfortunately `text()` method will remove the icon span

Comment: @MirkoCianfarani because `find()` returns a jquery object